# How to add namespaces to XML before serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I do have a problem with serialization of a namespaces. As my code show below my logic fills the structure of my dictionary, serializes it and puts into a string variable. I use this variable to load into XMLDocument and after that I do add the namespaces. But since they are added after the serialization process the namespaces are set in UTF8? Should I add namespaces before serialization? If yes, how can I do it properly?

```
///Dictionary
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TestXML
{
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root")]
public class XMLSchema: Serialization
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Element1")]
    public XMLElement1 Element1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Element2")]
    public XMLElement2 Element2 { get; set; }

}
}


 ///Serialization class
 public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        // Use UTF8 encoding 
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return new UTF8Encoding(false); } 
        }
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        var Utf8StringWriter = new Utf8StringWriter();
        var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Utf8StringWriter))
        {
            xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, this, xns);
          return Utf8StringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }


    ///create xml
            str xml;
            [...] my logic to add data into elements
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            xml = XMLSchema.Serialize();

            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            
            XmlElement root = doc.getNamedElement("Root");
            root.SetAttribute("xmlns:etd", "http://google.com");
            root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://google.com");
            root.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://google.com");
            doc.AppendChild(root);

            doc.Save(path);
```

Edit. Adding provided sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    <XMLSample xmlns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/">
```

Comment: You should set the namespaces correctly in the attributes (they all have a `Namespace` property). Note child elements will inherit their namespace from their parent, so you don't need to explicitly specify every single one. However, you won't be able to replicate the attributes you are adding after - you are setting 3 prefixes to the same namespace - the serialiser will only use one of those.

Comment: So short you're saying thay if I serialize it as it is there will be only one namespace output? I see the setAtributes2 method has a namespace property yet I don't know how to use it right... trying to add xmlns:etd the file showed me xmlns:d1p1. My code produces a xml that matches with the sample xml provided for API yet I don't know if the encoding hits the same way and it passes the verification.

Comment: Have you got an example you can add to the question? I suspect having 3 with the same mapping isn't what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Added. The samples send with the documentation have this declaration in root elements. In the documentation is only that he document needs to be in UTF-8 nothing more about the root element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to give you an example (based on your sample):

```cs
[XmlRoot("XMLSample", Namespace = "http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/")]
public class XmlSample
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Element1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/")]
    public string Element2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here, the root has the namespace `http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/`. `Element1` inherits that namespace (as none is specified). `Element2` has the namespace `http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/`.

When this is serialised, the serialiser will use the root namespace as the default, so there's no need to explicitly set this. You can set the others to use the prefixes as defined in your sample:

```cs
var xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xsn.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/");
xsn.Add("etd", "http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/");
```

You can see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KKCSnu) for a demo, the output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLSample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/" xmlns:etd="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/" xmlns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/">
  <Element1>foo</Element1>
  <etd:Element2>bar</etd:Element2>
</XMLSample>
```

Note that `Element2` uses the prefix configured for its namespace.

Comment: Thank you it helped, in this sample I dont have these prefixes in but I did see them on a different xml for their other Api. There was no 'main' namespace it had :etd, :tns, :xsi and all elements with root had this :tns prefix.